# How can I align my custom CSS images perfectly without running into issues when I change screen size?

Tags: css

So I'm trying to make this custom image gallery set up and I realized once I resized my screen that the alignment of the shapes are slightly off, so using % isn't going to work out for me.

I was thinking about making a container around everything with a max width and height, but I'm not sure how I'd edit the CSS positioning to ensure that no matter how big the screen, the position of the elements will remain centered in the container.

[image]

```
 .images {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
-webkit-clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 95% 25%, 95% 75%, 50% 100%, 5% 75%, 5% 25%);
clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 95% 25%, 95% 75%, 50% 100%, 5% 75%, 5% 25%);
 }

 .slide-border:nth-child(1) {
top: 50%;
left: 25%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
 }

 .slide-border:nth-child(2){
top: 50%;
left: 25%;
transform: translate(-5%, 25%);
 }

.slide-border:nth-child(3){
top: 25%;
left:25%;
transform: translate(40%, 14%);
}
```

here's the html

```
 <div class="img-gallery">
    <div class="slide slide-border">
        <img class="images" src="gallery/img-1.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="slide slide-border">
        <img class="images" src="gallery/img-2.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="slide slide-border">
        <img class="images" src="gallery/img-3.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
 </div>
```

Here is the container size

```
 .img-gallery {
margin: 0 auto;
width: 50%;
height: 80vh;
max-width: 80rem;
position: relative;
border: 2px solid pink;
overflow: hidden;
 }
```

[image]

So I managed to get them align using floats, but whenever I resize the screen two pictures awkwardly move down while the rest of the images stay in place? Also, how do I fit all these images within the pink box while maintaining the same exact look?

```
       .slide-border:nth-child(1) {
            float: left;
        }

        .slide-border:nth-child(2){
            float: right;
        }


        .slide-border:nth-child(3){
            float: left;
            margin-top: calc((100% /2) * -.20);
            transform: translateX(50%);
        }

        .slide-border:nth-child(4){
            float: left;
            margin-top: calc((100% /2) * -.20);
            transform: translateX(50%);
        }

        .slide-border:nth-child(5){
            float: left;
            margin-top: calc((100%/2) * -.8);
            transform: translateX(-50%);
        }

        .slide-border:nth-child(6){
            float: left;
            margin-top: calc((100% /2) * -.20);
            transform: translateX(0%);
        }


        .slide-border:nth-child(7){
            float: left;
            margin-top: calc((100% /2) * -.8);
            transform: translateX(0%);
        }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

The code is simple enough to understand, nevertheless if there's any questions please leave a comment :)

```css
.img-gallery {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid;
  resize: horizontal;
  overflow: auto;
  
  /* For demo not needed */
  width:50%;
}

.slide-border {
  width: 50%;
  font-size: 0;
}

.images {
  width: 100%;
  clip-path: polygon( 50% 0%, 100% 25%, 100% 75%, 50% 100%, 0% 75%, 0% 25%);
}

.slide-border:nth-child(1) {
  float: left;
}

.slide-border:nth-child(2) {
  float: left;
}

.slide-border:nth-child(3) {
  float: left;
  /* raising the third element by one third of the half 
   * Why one third of the half ? Because 
   * that's how the polygon is setup
  */
  margin-top: calc((100% /2) * -.25);
  transform: translateX(50%);
}
```

```html
Bottom right corner to resize.
<div class="img-gallery">
  <div class="slide slide-border">
    <img class="images" src="https://picsum.photos/id/124//300" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="slide slide-border">
    <img class="images" src="https://picsum.photos/id/123//300" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="slide slide-border">
    <img class="images" src="https://picsum.photos/id/125/300" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
```

There's probably a better way than this.

---

**Note:** With this, if the top row of images didn't load fast enough there will be layout quirkiness, to fix this, put an element to clear the float between the last image from the top row, and first images from the second row.  https://jsfiddle.net/7bL6ar2p/

Comment: I can't use float because I have a center div that I'm trying to center everything inside it in the middle. Floating just brings it to the top left which defeats the purpose of my custom top: and left: percentages that. I have above. Eventually I want to add multiple images and form like a honeycomb style, so I need something that would just perfectly align everything withing my div

Comment: Well, You didn't say anything concerning outer elements, i suggest editing your question with appropriate constrains. With that being said, the solution relays on having  a container holding the images, it's width can change and it will keep the aspect ratio of the images, that container can be put anywhere, the floats are only inside the container holding the images.

Comment: I added the code to container that all the images are in. Floats wouldn't work with my restraints

Comment: It doesn't seem like you understood what I said, the images will have their own container, you don't touch that container, think of it as the image which needs to be inside another container, Also i don't understand how it doesn't work https://jsfiddle.net/zw6hmLtr/ if it's about the images being cut off on the bottom change `overflow:hidden` to `auto`

Comment: so I kinda got it to work, but I need a way to make all the images go within my container because right now the overflow extends outside of my parent div and I need the images to fit within the pink box. The overflow: auto makes it scroll which looks weird and I need it to be static so you can see everything as is. Also, do you know why those two images on the left move down when I resize my screen, but the rest stay fixed in place?

Comment: The answer only dealt with 3 pictures 2 on the top row, if you plan on adding more you will have to align them accordingly. https://jsfiddle.net/68gb2pej/ If you want the images to care about the height as well you'd need something like this https://jsfiddle.net/0xaL9ocd/ but that will distort the aspect ratio